# Как разрезать объекты в Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Нужно разрезать объект с Rigitbody и BoxCollider2d так, чтобы у двух кусков появился коллайд на месте среза и верхний соскользнул с нижнего. Есть игровой курсор, которым разрезаю, считываю его координаты при начале разрезания и по завершении при помощи методов OnTrigger. Таким образом можно провести линию среза. Проблема лишь в том как разрезать и реализовать механику с отдельными коллайдерами.

Comment: удалить старый и добавить 2 новых?

Comment: Уточните в чем проблема, в рассечении меша, в алгоритме, в механике?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загуглил "unity cut sprite and collider"

и первая же ссылка ведет на готовый гит-репозиторий, который реализует разрезание спрайта в два меша.

https://github.com/sabikku/unity-sprite-cutter

и по тому же запросу статья:
https://gamedevacademy.org/how-to-create-a-fruit-ninja-game-in-unity/

---

*Пожалуста, раз я нашел тебе 2 решения вместо тебя - сделай апдейт этого ответа с конечным кодом который ты напишешь на основе этих ссылок)*